# unlist and merge into a single dataframe in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I have a list of dataframes that I need to be combined into a single one.

```
year<-1990:2000
v1<-1:11
v2<-20:30
df1<-data.frame(year,v1)
df2<-data.frame(year,v2)
ldf<-list(df1,df2)
```

I now want to unlist this dataframe and get

```
> head(df)
   year v1 v2
1  1990  1 20
2  1991  2 21
3  1992  3 22
4  1993  4 23
```

Note that my question is **different** from the solution provided in a similar question, where the solution to that question was: `df <- ldply(ldf, data.frame)

Because what I am essentially looking for, is a more automatic way of doing this: `df<-merge(df1,df2, by="year")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With more number of `list` elements, a convenient option is `reduce` with one of the join functions

```
library(tidyverse)
ldf %>%
     reduce(inner_join, by = "year")
#   year v1 v2
#1  1990  1 20
#2  1991  2 21
#3  1992  3 22
#4  1993  4 23
#5  1994  5 24
#6  1995  6 25
#7  1996  7 26
#8  1997  8 27
#9  1998  9 28
#10 1999 10 29
#11 2000 11 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with:

```
df <- merge(ldf[[1]], ldf[[2]], by="year")
```

Or for a long list:

```
df1 <- ldf[[1]]
for (x in 2:length(ldf)) {
  df1 <- merge(df1, ldf[[x]])
}
# year v1 v2
# 1  1990  1 20
# 2  1991  2 21
# 3  1992  3 22
# 4  1993  4 23
# 5  1994  5 24
# 6  1995  6 25
# 7  1996  7 26
# 8  1997  8 27
# 9  1998  9 28
# 10 1999 10 29
# 11 2000 11 30
```

Comment: Not at all, I just thought that might be a similar rbind approach :)